# When and how read/write blocks (i.e. suspends your program) for different kind of files?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I think I am not clear about when and how read/write blocks for various kind of files.
(disk file, pipe, socket, FIFO)

Could any one explain for both read and write scenarios of each file type?

Thanks!!

Comment: What's the difference between "pipe" and "FIFO"?

Comment: @kai, I think you will have better luck if you ask _how_ to do something specific, or _what_ a specific piece of code does.  As written, this question is too vague...

Comment: Am I right in guessing that "blocks" is the key part of the question (it's kind of buried in the sentence)? So you're asking, what are the differences in possible blocking situations when reading from or writing to these types of files?

Comment: guess he is asking about buffered read and write ?

Comment: This question is too confused to be able to answer in its current form. Try giving a specific example in code that you think will behave differently with the different kinds of file, and describe what you think the difference in behavior might be.

Comment: Pipes are anonymous; FIFOs are not.  Pipes have a finite buffer size on most systems; I'm not sure that FIFOs do (but there is a limit {PIPE_BUF} on the size of atomic reads and writes).  See the POSIX [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) call, in particular.

Comment: Thanks for all of you for responding.
I am sorry that I didn't write my question in a clear way. @@
But I think duskwuff's answer is what I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a disk-based file, `read` and `write` may block briefly while the requested read/write is performed. A `read` at the end of a file will always return a short result, and a `write` to a file on a full FS will fail -- barring various unusual circumstances, `read`/`write` to a plain file will never block indefinitely.

For pipes, sockets, and FIFOs, `read` will block if no data is available, and `write` will block if the pipe/socket/FIFO is "full" (*e.g*, you've written a bunch of data and the process on the other end hasn't read it yet). The exact amount of data required to fill the buffer is variable; for a pipe, for instance, it's typically between 4 and 64 kB.

Comment: So for pipes, sockets, and FIFOs, read and write could block indefinitely?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Consider shell pipelines: if you've got a pipeline `foo | bar`, and `foo` isn't writing anything to standard output, `bar` will sit there blocked on `read(stdin)` until either something shows up, or the pipe closes.